# NoMachine Authentication failed when tunnel to ssh connection

Tags: nomachine-nx, nomachine

I followed this link (https://www.nomachine.com/AR10K00728) to try to connect by ssh. But after those setting, when I login in the NoMachine client GUI, I always meet "Authentication failed" after entering my username and password. Any suggestions on this? Thanks in advance.

Dan

Comment: Do you authenticate correctly if you connect to the NoMachine server with NX protocol without the tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

Either your NoMachine app is not allowing your username or the  ssh server on your NoMachine host is actually not allowing Password authentication.

Try enabling the `PasswordAuthentication yes` options in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and restart the ssh server. i.e `service ssh restart`

Comment: `PasswordAuthentication yes` was already enabled... but still has that failure